# Can't get toggle with jQuery to work in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the following function to use content and it seems to work fine in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2k21oyv/) but when i put it in my wordpress theme it doesn't work:

Here is the [link](http://goo.gl/IjmthZ) to my page and i am trying to put the goggle in the information icon on the right hand side

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#toggle-view li').click(function () {

    var text = $(this).children('div.panel');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        $(this).children('span').html('-');     
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
        $(this).children('span').html('+');     
    }

});

});
```

Comment: getting any errors in console??

Comment: no not getting any errors

Comment: try use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: post your html also..

Comment: @user38208 you should provide minimal complete example, representing problem. Looking at site with tons of HTML, CSS and JS and trying to find `#toggle-view` element on site's page is nothing even close to good for me.

Comment: It works as soon as I manually execute the script on your page (and replace $ with jQuery).
So the script isn't the problem, the problem is, it doesn't get executed.

Comment: It is giving me **TypeError: "#toggle-view li".click is not a function** .Have you tried Bhoomi Shah's solution ?

Comment: Go in view page source and press `ctrl + f` to find out `toggle-view`.You will find that it is in hidden div.So you might not able to see on front end.

Comment: @Regent You can not use that code as I have mentioned in earlier comment that it is giving error which needs to be solved.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner by the way, there was no this error 25 minutes ago. Right now `$` is simply missed (`('#toggle-view li')` instead of `$('#toggle-view li')`). But even if it will be fixed, I don't want to open site again.

Comment: @Regent OP might have changed something in code. Let it be as OP is not even responding.

Comment: @mahe any solution on how to execute it then?

Answer (score 0):

Use code like

```
(function($) {

$('#toggle-view li').click(function () {

    var text = $(this).children('div.panel');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        $(this).children('span').html('-');     
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
        $(this).children('span').html('+');     
    }

});
})(jQuery);
```

UPDATE:

add following line in functions.php

```
function my_wp_enqueue_script() {    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/test.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );  
}     
  add_action( 'init', 'my_wp_enqueue_script' );
```

and provided above code of js into test.js

Comment: How is this code better than `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });` ?

Comment: wordpress uses like this. I have read from http://www.creativedev.in/2013/01/solutionuncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-in-wordpress/

Comment: But `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` also provides `$` as jQuery global object inside function local scope. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Your code or original one? Nevertheless, your code [doesn't work at all](http://jsfiddle.net/s2k21oyv/1/), does it?

Comment: @Regent It should work with Wordpress. I had came up with this issue so I know :)

Comment: check updated code above. it must work. as working here

Comment: I checked your code and mine code..both codes when the toggle content is not placed inside another toggle. I suspect it does not work for me as the toggle is placed inside another toggle